# Describing an advantage gained via a common background

Tags: word-choice, diction

I recently used the word 'nepotism' to describe an advantage attained due to sharing a common background. The person I said this to thought that that was too liberal an extension of the word. I agree, but I couldn't come up with anything better. What is the word that would describe this?

Comment: _Racism_ might be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chauvinism is the best fit I can think of. It makes clear that the partisanship is based on shared culture and nationality.

Answer (score 1):

This article compares different types of favoritism, including "Compatriotism," which sounds appropriate in your example:

http://m.jcc.sagepub.com/content/early/2010/09/08/0022022110381120.abstract

Answer (score 0):

I think [partisanship](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Partisanship) may suggest the idea you are referring to: (from TFD)

> - an inclination  to favor one group or view or opinion over alternatives.

also [lobbyism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lobbyism)  is used to refer to :

> - A group of persons engaged in trying to influence legislators or other public officials in favor of a specific cause: the nationalistic lobby; the labor lobby etc.

[Nepotism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Partisanship) may work especially if the common background is family and relatives:

> - nepotism - favoritism shown to relatives or close friends by those in power (as by giving them jobs)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Josh 61, nepotism wouldn't fit.

> [**nepotism**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nepotism) -  the unfair practice by a powerful person of giving jobs and other favors to relatives

I would suggest **"cultural discrimination"** or **"cultural bias"**

A bias may be favorable or unfavorable."e.g. "He showed a bias toward a few workers in particular."  "My boss seems to be biased against.../in favor of..."

> [**bias**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bias) - noun - "a tendency to believe that some people, ideas, etc., are better than others that usually results in treating some people unfairly"

Answer (score -1):

at the risk of being voted down i would say "homecourt advantage" is quite popular in  the English-speaking world...

Comment: This really only works if the common background that provides the advantage is the same one in which the advantage is being offered in. A Brit living in Nashville, Tennessee giving a job to a another Brit based upon his origins isn't a situation in which anyone's really enjoying a "homecourt advantage".

Answer (score -2):

how about "simpatico" - essentially being on the same wavelength as someone else or people (so to speak)...

Comment: You can be ¨simpatico¨ with somebody from an entirely different background, and not simpatico at all with somebody from your own home-town, nation etc.  It refers to with compatible personality types, or highly empathic people.  It isn´t really relevant and even if it were, you are not showing how it could be used to describe advantage gained through this empathic connection.